# Exit() function call not being recognised as crash in device log

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my iOS app, I have used an `exit(-1)` call inside a condition block, i.e if the `performFetch` function of `NSFetchedResultsController` returns `Yes` as error. This is the skeleton code

```
NSFetchedResultsController *resultsContoller;
NSError *error;

if (![resultsContoller performFetch:&error]) {

   exit(-1);
}
```

Initializations for the NSfetchedResultsController are done in my code.

So, here is my question. The app does crash at this point due to the `exit()` call. But when I see my iPhone's device log through XCode there is no crash report registered.

1. Is programatically calling `exit()` not considered as a crash in iOS?
2. Are only unexpected calls to `exit()` registered in the device log?

Comment: I guess this might be because the exit() function probably triggers a programmatic closing of the app, not a "crash" per se. Have you tried calling fatalError() instead?

Answer (score 1):

**Is programatically calling exit() not considered as a crash in iOS?**

> Applications calling exit will appear to the user to have crashed,
>   rather than performing a graceful termination and animating back to
>   the Home screen.

**Are only unexpected calls to exit() registered in the device log?**

No, exit() will not registered in the device log as it is actual closing of app not crash.

> If during development or testing it is necessary to terminate your
>   application, the abort function, or assert macro is recommended.

Like, `NSAssert(FALSE, @"Quitting the app programmatically.");`

Check reference here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1561/_index.html